# Entities being stripped from formatted field

Tags: 8, input-formats

I have a formatted text field using the basic_html filter, which is set up like this:

[image: enabled filters]

[image: allowed HTML tags]

It is removing HTML unicode entities, in the format `&#x<hex>;` for example, the Euro symbol is `&#x80;` which becomes €.

But this is not appearing in content. When I look at the source code, it is showing a little box, e.g. €65 becomes [image: box]. But if I edit the node in CKEditor, it shows the Euro symbol there.

If I call `$node->get('field_my_field')` then I see the values is an array like:

```
$values = [
  'value' => 'Content\n<br />Example content: &#x80;65',
  'format' => 'basic_html',
];
```

So at some point when it goes through check_markup(), this entity is being turned into a Unicode character which is then for some reason invisible on the page.

I've tried all sorts of messing around with html_entity_decode() and htmlspecialchars() but just end up breaking the HTML tags. I'm not sure what I can do other than a str_replace() of all possible entities I think might occur.